# Ckeditor edit input element inline

Tags: ckeditor

I have an ckeditor and added an button for inserting textfields

```
config.toolbar = [
    ...
    { name: 'forms', items: [ 'TextField' ] },
    ...
```

inserting works fine, but for editing i have to doubleclick the input and change the value in the dialog

is it possible to allow to edit the content just within the textfield?

Comment: Apparently not. I'm also looking for a way to do this. Have you found a solution?

Comment: unfortunately  not, we are now using the popup